# Actions in interactive notification not reflecting in app

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8

I am doing a sample app for using ios 8 interactive notification feature. Everything is working fine as far as displaying notifications.But when i select a action in the notification the respective method for the action is called, but code inside that method is not reflecting in the app.

**My app delegate part of code where notifications are implemented**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
 [self setupNotification];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
return YES;
}

-(void)setupNotification
{
UIMutableUserNotificationAction *accept =[[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc]init];
accept.identifier =@"Accepted";
accept.title=@"Accept";
accept.destructive=NO;
accept.authenticationRequired=YES;
accept.activationMode=UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground;

UIMutableUserNotificationAction *decline =[[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc]init];
decline.identifier =@"Rejected";
decline.title=@"Decline";
decline.destructive=YES;
decline.authenticationRequired=YES;
decline.activationMode=UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground;

UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *actions =[[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc]init];
[actions setIdentifier:@"customActions"];
[actions setActions:@[decline,accept] forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];

NSSet* categories = [NSSet setWithArray:@[actions]];
UIUserNotificationSettings* settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert) categories:categories];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
{
  if([notification.category isEqualToString:@"customActions"])
{
     ViewController *screen =[[ViewController alloc]init];
    if([identifier isEqualToString:@"Rejected"])
    {

        [screen deleteAction];
    }
    else if([identifier isEqualToString:@"Accepted"])
    {
        [screen acceptAction];
    }
}

//  Important to call this when finished
completionHandler();
}
```

My view controller

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    -(void)deleteAction
    {
    NSLog(@"delete");
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    }
    -(void)acceptAction
   {
   NSLog(@"accept");
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    }

    - (IBAction)sendNotification:(id)sender {

    UILocalNotification* notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    [notification fireDate  ];
    [notification setAlertBody:@"Notification triggered"];
    [notification setCategory:@"customActions"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
     }
```

log inside the methods are printing but background colour is not changing. Help me i need to implement this feature in my existing app.

Comment: I have the same problem and don not know why it is not showing the action buttons

Comment: I'm getting the action buttons, but nothing happens on the click event

Answer (score 0):

In swift, add:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, forLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification, completionHandler: () -> Void) {
    Swift.print(identifier)
}
```

in AppDelegate. It will called once you press the action button in notification